# llenar tabla desde xml en postgres

Tags: postgresql, xml

Tengo el siguiente problema ocupo hacer un insert a una tabla desde un xml pero solo inserta el primer registro, cuando deberia de estar sacando 4 registros del xml
el xml es parecido al siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ASN>
    <IDENTIFICACION>
        <NUM_PROVEEDOR>38792</NUM_PROVEEDOR>
        <ORDEN_COMPRA>28091399</ORDEN_COMPRA>
        <NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN>18</NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN>
        <NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO>1</NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO>
        <UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO>1</UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO>
        <FOLIO_CFDI_TRASLADO>1</FOLIO_CFDI_TRASLADO>
        <TOTAL_LOTES>3</TOTAL_LOTES>
        <TOTAL_CANTIDAD_PEDIDA>18</TOTAL_CANTIDAD_PEDIDA>
        <ID_EMBARQUE>1234567890</ID_EMBARQUE>
    </IDENTIFICACION>
    <LOTES>
        <LOTE>
            <NUM_LOTE>1</NUM_LOTE>
            <ID_LOTE>12345</ID_LOTE>
            <CODIGOS>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>282</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>300</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
            </CODIGOS>
        </LOTE>
        <LOTE>
            <NUM_LOTE>2</NUM_LOTE>
            <CODIGOS>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>282</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>300</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
            </CODIGOS>
        </LOTE>
    </LOTES>
</ASN>
```

para insertarlo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO Ctl_asnLevis10 (num_proveedor,num_ordenCompra,num_bodegaOrigen,num_bodegaDestino,uuid_cfdiTraslado,
        total_lotes,total_cantidadPedida,num_lote,upc,sku,talla,cantidad,costo)
SELECT ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/NUM_PROVEEDOR/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/ORDEN_COMPRA/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN/text()', asn))[1])::text::smallint,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO/text()', asn))[1])::text::smallint,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/TOTAL_LOTES/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'IDENTIFICACION/TOTAL_SURTIDO/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'LOTES/LOTE/NUM_LOTE/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'LOTES/LOTE/CODIGOS/CODIGO/UPC/text()', asn))[1])::text::bigint,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'LOTES/LOTE/CODIGOS/CODIGO/sku/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'LOTES/LOTE/CODIGOS/CODIGO/TALLA/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'LOTES/LOTE/CODIGOS/CODIGO/CANTIDAD/text()', asn))[1])::text::int,
       ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'LOTES/LOTE/CODIGOS/CODIGO/COSTO/text()', asn))[1])::text::numeric(9,2);
```

esto en sql server lo puedo hacer muy facil pero en postgres no e podido hacer que se inserte toda la info solo pone un registro, si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria mucho, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí en PostgreSQL también es muy fácil, existe la función llamada `XMLTABLE` así que si usas PostgreSQL 10 o superior , la podrás utilizar de este modo:

```
SELECT tabla_xml.*
FROM  (VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ASN>
    <IDENTIFICACION>
        <NUM_PROVEEDOR>38792</NUM_PROVEEDOR>
        <ORDEN_COMPRA>28091399</ORDEN_COMPRA>
        <NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN>18</NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN>
        <NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO>1</NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO>
        <UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO>1</UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO>
        <FOLIO_CFDI_TRASLADO>1</FOLIO_CFDI_TRASLADO>
        <TOTAL_LOTES>3</TOTAL_LOTES>
        <TOTAL_CANTIDAD_PEDIDA>18</TOTAL_CANTIDAD_PEDIDA>
        <ID_EMBARQUE>1234567890</ID_EMBARQUE>
    </IDENTIFICACION>
    <LOTES>
        <LOTE>
            <NUM_LOTE>1</NUM_LOTE>
            <ID_LOTE>12345</ID_LOTE>
            <CODIGOS>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>282</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>300</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
            </CODIGOS>
        </LOTE>
        <LOTE>
            <NUM_LOTE>2</NUM_LOTE>
            <CODIGOS>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>282</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
                <CODIGO>
                    <UPC>193151393821</UPC>
                    <sku>144392</sku>
                    <TALLA>300</TALLA>
                    <CANTIDAD>6</CANTIDAD>
                    <COSTO>150.78</COSTO>
                </CODIGO>
            </CODIGOS>
        </LOTE>
    </LOTES>
</ASN>'::xml)) AS t (dato) ,
XMLTABLE ('/ASN/LOTES/LOTE/CODIGOS/CODIGO'
PASSING t.dato
COLUMNS 
NUM_PROVEEDOR text PATH '../../../../IDENTIFICACION/NUM_PROVEEDOR' ,
ORDEN_COMPRA text PATH '../../../../IDENTIFICACION/ORDEN_COMPRA' ,
NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN text PATH '../../../../IDENTIFICACION/NUM_BODEGA_ORIGEN' ,
NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO text PATH '../../../../IDENTIFICACION/NUM_BODEGA_DESTINO' ,
UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO text PATH '../../../../IDENTIFICACION/UUID_CFDI_TRASLADO' ,
TOTAL_LOTES text PATH '../../../../IDENTIFICACION/TOTAL_LOTES' ,
NUM_LOTE text PATH '../../NUM_LOTE' ,
UPC text PATH 'UPC',
sku int PATH 'sku',
TALLA int PATH 'TALLA',
CANTIDAD int PATH 'CANTIDAD',
COSTO numeric PATH 'COSTO') tabla_xml;
```

La salida será algo como :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego podras hacer en `insert` en la tabla que requeires con un:

`insert into  Ctl_asnLevis10  select ...XMLTABLE...;`

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta lamentablemente usamos la version 9.3